# Which monoids have a faithful irreducible representation?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $*$ be a binary operation on a set $M$, with an identity element $e\in M$.

A *monoid representation* of $(M,*,e)$ is a map $\delta:M\to (S\to S)$ for some set $S$, such that $\delta(e)=\mathrm{id}_S$, and $\delta(a*b)=\delta(a)\circ\delta(b)$ for all $a,b\in M$. (A representation could also be called an *action*, I suppose?)

- $\delta$ is *faithful* if $\delta$ is injective as a function from $M$ to $S^S$.
- $\delta$ is *irreducible* if there is no subset $\emptyset\subsetneq T\subsetneq S$ with $\delta(m)(t)\in T$ for all $t\in T$ and $m\in M$.

Which monoids $(M,*,e)$ have faithful irreducible representations?
For example, all groups do have such representations, but the monoid $\{e,a\}$ with $a^2=a\ne e$ does not since we can take $T=\{\delta(a)(t)\}$ for a fixed $t\in S$.

> Is there a characterization, or a name for such monoids?

Example: let $M$ be generated by $f,g:\{0,1,2,3\}\to\{0,1,2,3\}$
where $f(0)=1$, $g(0)=2$, $f(1)=g(1)=1$, and $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=2$, $g(2)=3$, $g(3)=3$. The monoid is
$$\begin{matrix}
   &  && e &&\\
   &&f   & &g\\
&f^2  & gf&&fg & g^2\\
&     & fgf&&&fg^2\\
\end{matrix}$$
which has the ideals:
$$M(gf)=\{fgf,gf\}, M(g^2)=\{g^2,fg^2\}\quad\text{(minimal)}$$
$$ M(f),M(g) \quad\text{(not minimal)}$$

Comment: Yes, it is known I will answer this later in the day, but it is better irreducible is usually used for matrix reps (and we know what these are too).  I prefer the term transitive or minimal.  Also the answer depends on whether you allow only total mappings and partial mappings.   More to come.

Comment: Basically it has one if and only if it has a faithful left action on some (=any) of its minimal left ideals.  Rhodes calls these left mapping semigroups with respect to their minimal ideal (he also allows partial mappings which allows other L-classes.  There can be represented faithfully then as column monomial matrices over the maximal subgroup of their minimal ideal.

Comment: I should say the answer is well known in the finite case.  The infinite case I'd have to think a bit.

Comment: For (possibly infinite) abelian monoids $M$, if I'm correct, the answer is that $M$ admits a faithful minimal $M$-set iff $M$ is a group.

Comment: @Ycor that is correct and proved in the Tully paper in my answer. A commutative semigroup has a faithful transitive representation iff it is a group.

Comment: The endomorphism monoid of a transitive action acts fixed point-free.  A commutative monoid acts by endomorphisms of its own action so a faithful transitive action is fixed point free. Also its by onto maps since the image is invariant for each element.  Now if a in M and then if s is in S and b is in M with bas=s then ba=1.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes, this proves that the monoid $M$ acts by permutations, hence embeds into a group $G$ (generated by $M$), the minimal faithful action being on, say, $G/H$. Since $M$ is abelian one has (writing additively) $G=M-M$. Since $M$ acts faithfully, $(M-M)\cap H=\{1\}$. This implies $H=\{1\}$. But then $M$ is an $M$-invariant nonempty subset of the minimal $M$-set $G$, so $M=G$.

Comment: @YCor my argument showed that the inverse of a is b so it's a group

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg you got $ba=1$. But OK I see: given $x$, $aba(x)=a(x)$, so $a(x)$ is fixed by $ab$, so $ab=1$ too.

Comment: @YCor it's commutative do ab=ba

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg ha of course, lost track of this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cleaner rewrite:**

I have a bit more time, so here is a cleaner rewrite.  This notion is usually called transitive rather than irreducible, although the terms irreducible and minimal are both used.

If $M$ has a minimal left ideal $L$,then $L$ is a transitive $M$-set and every transitive action is a quotient of $L$ and hence $M$ has a faithful transitive action iff it acts faithfully on $L$.  In particular, if $M$ is finite then all its minimal left ideals are isomorphic as $M$-sets (since they are quotients of each other and finite) and $M$ has faithful transitive action iff it acts faithfully on one (equals all) of its minimal left ideals.

The proof is trivial.  If $S$ is a transitive $M$-set, then $Ls$ is invariant and hence $Ls=S$ for all $s\in S$.  Thus,  if we fix $s\in S$, then $m\mapsto ms$ is a surjective $M$-set map $L\to S$.

There is some information on Clifford and Preston Volume 2, Chapter 11.5 on the infinite case. For instance they show noncommutative free monoids have a faithful and transitive action and nontrivial free products of semigroups. See also Tully, E. J. (1961). Representation of a Semigroup by Transformations Acting Transitively on a Set. American Journal of Mathematics, 83(3), 533.

**Further Remark** It is more common to consider transitive actions by partial mappings because many more semigroups have  faithful transitive actions in this setting.

Comment: I gave a cleaner rewrite of the argument to drop extraneous stuff.

Comment: I added an example for "If M is a finite monoid, then all minimal left ideals of M are isomorphic as left M-sets" now :)

Comment: For group actions on topological spaces, "transitive" is much weaker than "minimal".

Comment: @YCor For actions on non discrete spaces also these two concepts diverge

Comment: Of semigroups I should have said